# Visual Studio 2015 (C++) sqlite3.dll unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2015, sqlite

I cannot figure out how to get sqlite3.dll (or any dll for that matter) to work with my C++ project in Visual Studio.

The error message I get is **LNK2001 unresolved external symbol sqlite3_open**

Here's what I did so far:

- I put the .dll in myProjectFoler/Resources/sqlite3.dll
- I generated sqlite3.lib using Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt using a command `lib /def:sqlite3.def`
- I referenced the directory with the lib in *Project -> Preferences -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library directories*, and then referenced the .lib in  *Project -> Preferences -> Linker -> Input-> Additional dependencies*
- I placed sqlite3.h in my project and #included it

(pretty much followed the instructions seen [here](https://dcravey.wordpress.com/2011/03/21/using-sqlite-in-a-visual-c-application/))

Thank you for help

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that by default the header file assumes that sqlite is linked statically, as opposed to dynamic linking to a dll.

This part of sqlite3.h is responsible for that:

```
#ifndef SQLITE_API
# define SQLITE_API
#endif
```

If you set a per-project define in project properties:

```
SQLITE_API=__declspec(dllimport)
```

this should resolve your link error.
Alternatively, you can put

```
#define SQLITE_API __declspec(dllimport)
```

right before where you #include sqlite3.h.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by per-project define, but adding the code you provided before #include sqlite3.h unfortunately doesn't work

Comment: My bad, should be __declspec(dllimport)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but it still produces the same mistake **edit:** the only difference being it now says **__imp_sqlite3_open** instead of just **sqlite3_open**

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell exactly why the problem occurred. There are lots of reasons which could cause `LNK2001` error. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(LNK2001)&rd=true) contains good check list.

You could try to use `/VERBOSE` option to determine which files the linker references. Put this option in `Project -> Preferences -> Linker -> Command Line -> Additional Options`. Output should contains similar strings:

```
Searching e:\SQLite\sqlite-dll-win32-x86-3150100\sqlite3.lib:
      Found _sqlite3_open
         Referenced in ConsoleApplication2.obj
         Loaded sqlite3.lib(sqlite3.dll)
```

Pay attention to the VS runtime libraries, there should be no mixup between Debug and Release libraries.

Comment: So I added the verbose option and I'm guessing that if it doesn't say `found` after path/sqlite3.lib it didn't load it. But I don't understand, the path is definetly correct.

Comment: @finrod I've added linker output for the case of success. In other case double check your linker configuration. Do you build the same configuration as you configured, e.g. Debug and build Debug?

Comment: I've triple checked the linker configuration and I've set it for all configurations. In the meantime I've added the sqlite3.c to my project. It does make the build a bit longer but at least it works. I would like to figure this out though. Thanks for the effort.